# Sharing templates with Rails and Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, prototype

So I have a have a solution for this, but I wanted to get some opinions and see if there was a better way to do this.

My problem is basically that I list of data that will get generated on load by RoR and then have JS controls to view subsets.  I would rather not have to support two versions of what is basically the same HMTL. So my solution is this, I have a ruby partial that looks something like this:

```
<% value1 = jsmode ? '#{value1}' : object.value1
value2 = jsmode ? '#{value2}' : object.value2 $>
<div class="object_template">
<div><$= value1 $></div>
<div><%= value2 %></div>
</div>
```

So when I render the partial with ruby, I pass in a jsmode of false and it renders like a normal partial. Then I will render the partial again wrapped with a div with an ID of template but this time with a jsmode of true.  This will render the html with the #{} strings.  I can then pass the template to prototype Template object like this:

```
new Template($('template')).evaluate({value1: '111', value2: '222'});
```

So my question is, is there a better way to do this?

I know that I can use the #{} construct to pass variables to RoR if I wrap them with double quotes, but I need the #{} to render for the JS template.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general approach looks good and actually probably a little better than what I've done before in some cases.

However, it looks to me like you're actually rendering the JS version to a div and then passing that into Prototype Template. Template also accepts a string so you can just pass the raw js template straight to it. Unless I'm missing something, the #template div is not necessary on its own. So the string route is probably the better way to go.

From Rails, it would probably look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var raw_template = "#{escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'template', :locals => { :jsmode => true }))}";
  var output = new Template(raw_template).evaluate({value1: '111', value2: '222'});
  // Do something with the output
</script>
```

`escape_javascript` uses the following map:

```
JS_ESCAPE_MAP = {
  '\\'    => '\\\\',
  '</'    => '<\/',
  "\r\n"  => '\n',
  "\n"    => '\n',
  "\r"    => '\n',
  '"'     => '\\"',
  "'"     => "\\'" }
```

This means that given your suggested template, you should end up with a result along the lines of:

```
 var raw_template = "<div class=\"object_template\">\n<div>#{value1}<\/div>\n<div>#{value2}<\/div>\n<\/div>";
```

Which should do the trick nicely.

Comment: This is kind of what i wanted to do, but I was concerned about newlines on the template.  I haven't tested this yet, but will escape_js convert this into a single line?

Comment: Just to add to my comment.  JS has no HEREDOC construct.  I would have like to do to some sort of 
HEREDOC
 render partial
HEREDOC

What I found was people saying to use the HTML for that.